# Spring JMS Integration Unit Test leaves message on queue

Tags: unit-testing, activemq-classic, junit4, spring-jms

I am using Spring 4.3.5.Release and ActiveMQ 5.14.3 to handle message queuing.

Here is my definition from the application context file:

```
<!-- Activemq connection factory -->
<bean id="amqConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <!-- brokerURL, You may have different IP or port -->
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="${message.broker.url}" />
</bean>

<!-- Pooled Spring connection factory -->
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="amqConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- ======================================================= -->
<!-- JMS Send, define default destination and JmsTemplate -->
<!-- ======================================================= -->
<!-- Default Destination Queue Definition -->
<bean id="defaultDestination" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <!-- name of the queue -->
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="${default.message.queue}" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsDestinationResolver" class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver"/>

<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="defaultDestination" />
    <property name="destinationResolver" ref="jmsDestinationResolver"/>
    <property name="pubSubDomain" value="${pub.sub.domain}"/>
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="${receive.timeout}"/>
</bean>
```

And here is the code for creating a message on the default queue:

```
 public boolean sendResponse(final MyObjectDTO myObject) {
    boolean success = false;
    this.jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(ebvResponse);
    success = true;
    return success;
}
```

Here is my unit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations =
{ "classpath:/spring/my-platform-services-context.xml" })
@Transactional
public class MessageUtilTest extends TestCase {

    @Autowired
    private MessageUtil messageUtil;

    @Test
    public void testConvertSendMessageToDefault() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        MyObjectDTO myObject = new ManualCoverageDTO();
        myObject.setMessage(message);
        boolean success = messageUtil.sendResponse(myObject);
        assertEquals(true, success);
    }
}
```

This test works great, and a message gets on the queue correctly!

I expect when the test is over, because the unit test is Transactional, that the message would roll back off the queue, but it doesn't seem to be.

I know this is an "integrated" test since it is actually touching the ActiveMQ server and putting a message on the queue.

So, how can I make this really transactional, so that the message I just put on the queue really rolls back when it is done, do I have to manually tell this test to rollback?

I've have done hundreds of "integrated" unit tests with the database, and after every insert, update, or delete within one test, and the end of the test, the database is rolled back to the state it was before the test, I'd like the same thing to happen with my message queues or topics.

Any help with this would be great.   Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `sessionTransacted` on the `JmsTemplate` to `true`.

But, bear in mind that you won't be able to receive the test message anyplace, unless you commit it.